# Finding the strut length for 2 poses of Stewart Platform

Tags: python, numerical-analysis

Goal 1: Find a strut length p2, with the parameters x1 = 5, (x2, y2) = (0,6), L1 = L3 = 3, L2 = 3√2, γ = π/4, p1 = 5, p3 = 3, for which there are only two poses.

Goal 2: Calculate the intervals in p2, with the same parameters, for which there are 0, 2, 4, and 6 poses respectively.

All needs to be done using python.

I am extremely new to python. This is supposed to be a group project but half my group has ghosted.

I have some code for a function that gives me x and y and graphs the function. I am fairly certain that for the first part p2 is 4 from some previous problems. I feel like I need to find the roots of the function with p2 = 4, to prove there are only two poses? Also my plot looks like crap. I can't figure out how to use plt.plot properly.

Here's the code I've written so far.

```
import math
import sympy
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def function_file_out(theta, x1, x2, y2):
    L1 = 3
    L2 = 3*sympy.sqrt(2)
    L3 = 3
    p1 = 5
    p2 = 4
    p3 = 3
    yVal = sympy.pi/2

    A2 = L3*sympy.cos(theta)-x1
    B2 = L3*sympy.sin(theta)
    A3 = L2*sympy.cos(theta+yVal)-x2
    B3 = L2*sympy.sin(theta+yVal)-y2

    first = B3*((p2**2) - (p1**2) - (A2**2) - (B2**2))
    second = -B2*((p3**2) -( p1**2) - (A3**2) - (B3**2))
    N1 =  first + second
    third = -A3*((p2**2) - (p1**2) - (A2**2) - (B2**2))
    fourth = A2*((p3**2) - (p1**2) - (A3**2) - (B3**2))
    N2 = third + fourth
    D = 2*(A2*B3 - B2*A3)

    out = (N1**2) + (N2**2) - (p1**2) * (D**2)
    x = N1 / D
    y = N2 / D

    return out

x = symbols('x')
plot(function_file_out(x, 5, 0, 6), (x,-sympy.pi,sympy.pi))
```

I'm not really very sure about the second part at all. Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated.